# My code in JS isn't coming out with a letter grade

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a function in JS towards the end that is suppose to give you a letter grade once you get the average of 5 subjects, but it's not showing me anything
I'm lost right now

The forth function I wrote doesn't seem to produce any letter grade. I believe everything else is right

```js
function getHandleValue(idName) {
  const value = parseInt(document.getElementById(idName).value);
  console.log(value);
  return value;
}

function getTotal() {
  //console.log("app js starts loading")
  let english = getHandleValue('english');
  let math = getHandleValue('math');
  let physics = getHandleValue('physics');
  let computer = getHandleValue('computer');
  let science = getHandleValue('science');
  //console.log("app js ends loading")
  let total = english + math + physics + computer + science;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
  return total;

}

function getAverage() {
  // option  1
  // const total = parseInt(document.getElementById('total').innerHTML);
  // const average = total / 5;
  // document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = average;

  // option 2
  const average = getTotal() / 5;
  document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = average;
}

function letterGrade() {
  letterGrade;
  if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100)
    letterGrade = 'A';

  else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89)
    letterGrade = 'B';

  else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79)
    letterGrade = 'C';

  else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69)
    letterGrade = 'D';

  else if (grade > 1 && grade <= 59)
    letterGrade = 'F';

  let average = letterGrade;
  document.getElementById('Grade').innerHTML = Grade;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the same name for the variable and the function.

Comment: `document.getElementById('Grade').innerHTML = Grade;` You never set the variable `Grade`.

Comment: You assign the variable `average`, but never use it.

Comment: Thank you!!! Hopefully this can help solve my issue

Comment: Can you provide more code, like what is this letterGrade referring to, a global variable? if not you haven't declared this variable.

Answer (score 0):

`letterGrade` isn't declared properly, do:

```
let letterGrade = ' '
```

This declares the `letterGrade variable`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared the `lettergrade` variable. To do this, replace `letterGrade;` with `let letterGrade;`

In your code, this will look like:

```js
function getHandleValue(idName) {
  const value = parseInt(document.getElementById(idName).value);
  console.log(value);
  return value;
}

function getTotal() {
  //console.log("app js starts loading")
  let english = getHandleValue('english');
  let math = getHandleValue('math');
  let physics = getHandleValue('physics');
  let computer = getHandleValue('computer');
  let science = getHandleValue('science');
  //console.log("app js ends loading")
  let total = english + math + physics + computer + science;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
  return total;

}

function getAverage() {
  // option  1
  // const total = parseInt(document.getElementById('total').innerHTML);
  // const average = total / 5;
  // document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = average;

  // option 2
  const average = getTotal() / 5;
  document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = average;
}

function letterGrade() {
  let letterGrade;
  if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100)
    letterGrade = 'A';

  else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89)
    letterGrade = 'B';

  else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79)
    letterGrade = 'C';

  else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69)
    letterGrade = 'D';

  else if (grade > 1 && grade <= 59)
    letterGrade = 'F';

  let average = letterGrade;
  document.getElementById('Grade').innerHTML = Grade;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong because I'm still not producing a letter grade on my webpage after I've entered in 5 grades

Comment: You have the same problem as the OP. You're assigning `letterGrade` and `average`, but then putting the undeclared variable `Grade` in the result div.

Answer (score 0):

## Problems

I assume comments and answers have already stated, that the function `letterGrade()` doesn't use the correct variable `letterGrade` but instead uses an undefined variable `Grade`. Also, the variable `grade` is neither defined nor is it passed as a parameter or is within scope. **Figure I** is a breakdown of `letterGrade()`.

### Figure I

```js
function letterGrade() {
  /**
   * ISSUE 1 * Naming a Variable
   * Do not name a variable with the same name as the function in which it 
   * resides within
   * ISSUE 2 * Declaring or Defining a Variable
   * Use identifier var (not recommended), let, or const
   *   ex. let letter;
   */
  letterGrade; 
  /**
   * ISSUE 3 * Declaring or Defining Variables
   * grade isn't declared
   *   ex. let grade;
   * grade isn't defined
   *   ex. let grade = 0;
   * grade isn't a parameter
   *   ex. function letterGrade(grade) {...
   * grade isn't within scope
   *   ex. let grade = 0;
   *       function letterGrade() {...
   */
  if (grade >= 90 && grade <= 100)
    letterGrade = 'A';

  else if (grade >= 80 && grade <= 89)
    letterGrade = 'B';

  else if (grade >= 70 && grade <= 79)
    letterGrade = 'C';

  else if (grade >= 60 && grade <= 69)
    letterGrade = 'D';

  else if (grade > 1 && grade <= 59)
    letterGrade = 'F';
  
  /**
   * ISSUE 4 * Passing by Value
   * average is never used. If average is a reference to the value calculated 
   * by function getAverage(), then...
   *   - getAverage() should return that value, 
   *   - then that value must be defined outside of getAverage() 
   *   - or passed as a parameter of letterGrade() (recommennded).
   *     ex. ..::OUTSIDE OF letterGrade()::..
   *         function getAverage() {
   *           ...
   *           return average;
   *         }
   *         // Option A
   *         let average = getAverage()
   *         letterGrade(average)
   *         // Option B (recommended)
   *         letterGrade(getAverage)
   *
   *         ..::INSIDE OF letterGrade()::..
   *         function letterGrade(average) {
   *           let grade = typeof average === "number" ? grade : 0;
   *           ...
   *         }
   * Even if average was to be used, it would be useless as the value of
   * letterGrade, there's no point in reassigning it to another variable
   * unless it's to create a copy of another variable declared or defined 
   * outside of the function. 
   */
  let average = letterGrade;
  /**
   * ISSUE 5 * Defining or Declaring Variables
   * Grade variable has the same problem as ISSUE 3
   */
  document.getElementById('Grade').innerHTML = Grade;
}
```

## Solutions

Provided are two examples (**Example A** and **Example B**) that require familiarity with a few methods, properties, events, and techniques, please refer to **Appendix** located at the end of this answer. Both examples have step-by-step details commented within the source.

### Example A

**Example A** is a working example that comprises of:

- a `<form>` tag
- an `<input type="range">`
- two `<output>` tags
- an event handler `getGrade(e)`
- a functional `letterGrade(score)`

```js
/**
 * Reference <form>
 * Bind the "input" event to <form>
 */
const grade = document.forms.grade;
grade.oninput = getGrade;

/**
 * Event handler passes (e)vent object by default
 * Reference the tag the user is currently typing into
 * Reference all form controls (<fieldset>, <input>, <output>)
 * Reference both <output>
 * If the tag the user is currently using is NOT <form>
 * AND the tag is #score...
 * Assign the value of the currently used <input> as the
 * value of the first <output>
 * Next pass the same value to letterGrade(score) and assign
 * it's value to the second <output>
 */
function getGrade(e) {
  const dataIN = e.target;
  const io = this.elements;
  const number = io.number;
  const letter = io.letter;
  if (dataIN !== this && dataIN.id === "score") {
    number.value = dataIN.value;
    letter.value = letterGrade(dataIN.value);
  }
}

/**
 * Convert a given number in the range of 0 to 100 to a 
 * letter grade in the range of "A" to "F".
 * @param {Number} score - A number in the range of 0 to 100
 * @returns {String} - A letter in the range of "A" to "F"
 * @default {String} - A "" if the @param is out of the
 *          range of 0 to 100
 */
function letterGrade(score) {
  if (score >= 0 && score < 60) return "F";
  if (score >= 60 && score < 70) return "D";
  if (score >= 70 && score < 80) return "C";
  if (score >= 80 && score < 90) return "B";
  if (score >= 90 && score < 101) return "A";
  return "";
}
```

```css
label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

input {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<form id="grade">
  <label for="score">Set Score: </label>
  <label>
    0&nbsp;
    <input id="score" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0">
    &nbsp;100
  </label>
  <label>Score:&nbsp;<output id="number"></output></label>
  <label>Grade:&nbsp;<output id="letter"></output></label>
</form>
```

Note the pattern of the flow control statements in **Example A**:

```js
if (CONDITION) return LETTER;
if (CONDITION) return LETTER;
if (CONDITION) return LETTER;
if (CONDITION) return LETTER;
if (CONDITION) return LETTER;
return "";
```

If a `CONDITION` is `true` then a `LETTER` is returned. Whenever a value (`LETTER`) is returned, the function will terminate, so for example the third `CONDITION` is `true`, then the third `LETTER` is returned, the function ends, and the rest of the function doesn't execute. This technique is called a *short circuit*

### Example B

**Example B** is a working example comprising of:

- a `<form>`
- five `<input type="number">`
- two `<output>`
- an event handler `calc(e)`
- a terse version of `letterGrade(avg)` that uses ternary expressions

```js
/**
 * Reference <form>
 * Bind the "input" event to <form>
 */
const ga = document.forms.ga;
ga.oninput = calc;

/**
 * Event handler passes the (e)vent object by default
 * Reference the tag the user is entering text into
 * Reference all form controls (<fieldset>, <input>, <output>)
 * Collect all tags with [name="subject"] into an array
 * Reference the <output>
 * If the <input> that the user is currently using is NOT <form>...
 * AND if it is [name="subject"]...
 * convert the value of each <input> of the >subs< array into a
 * number, then use .reduce() to get the sum of all of them (>total<)
 * Next divide >total< by the .length of >subs<
 * Then get the letter grade determined by the given >average<
 * Then display the quotient as the value of the first <output>
 * Finally, display the letter grade as the value of the second <output>
 */
function calc(e) {
  const dataIN = e.target;
  const io = this.elements;
  const subs = Array.from(io.subject);
  const avg = io.avg;
  const grd = io.grd;
  if (dataIN !== this && dataIN.name === "subject") {
    const total = subs.reduce((sum, add) => +sum + parseInt(add.value), 0);
    const average = total / subs.length;
    const letter = grade(average);
    avg.value = average;
    grd.value = letter;
  }
}

/**
 * Given a number in the range of 0 to 100 return The letter grade equivalent.
 * @param {Number} avg - A number in the range of 0 to 100
 * @returns {String} - A letter grade "A" to "F"
 * @default {String} - If avg ts not within the range of 0 to 100, 
 * a "" is returned
 */
function grade(avg) {
  return avg >= 0 && avg < 60 ? "F" :
    avg >= 60 && avg < 70 ? "D" :
    avg >= 70 && avg < 80 ? "C" :
    avg >= 80 && avg < 90 ? "B" :
    avg >= 90 && avg < 101 ? "A" : "";
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 300 ch2/1.15 "Segoe UI"
}

fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 50vw;
  max-width: 60ch;
  margin: auto;
}

legend {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.25rem 1rem;
}

.last+label {
  margin-top: 1.25rem;
}

input,
output {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6ch;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
}

output {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<form id="ga">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Subjects</legend>
    <label>English: <input id="eng" name="subject" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0"></label>
    <label>Math: <input id="mat" name="subject" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0"></label>
    <label>History: <input id="his" name="subject" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0"></label>
    <label>Science: <input id="sci" name="subject" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0"></label>
    <label class="last">Art: <input id="art" name="subject" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0"></label>
    <label>Average: <output id="avg"></output></label>
    <label>Grade: <output id="grd"></output></label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

### Appendix

- [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)
- [Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)
- [Inline Event Handlers are Garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)
- [HTMLFormElement Interface](https://javascript.info/form-elements)
- [HTMLFormControlsCollection Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
- [List of Form Controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content)
- [Scope and Closures](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-closure/#:%7E:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20a%20closure%20is,the%20lexical%20scoping%20works%20first)

Answer (score -1):

**NOTES**

- This is a fully working example of how you can go about calculating the grades in a generic way without having to use ids for each subject input.
- By building it this way, you can add more subjects without changing the calculation logic.
- Also if you do not put a value for a subject than it will not be used in the calculations.

**HTML**

```html
<div>
    <section><label>Total:</label><span id="total">0</span></section>
    <section><label>Average:</label><span id="average">0</span></section>
    <section><label>Grade:</label><span id="grade">-</span></section>
</div>
<br />
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <label>English:</label><input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" name="english" value="0" /><br />
    <label>Math:</label><input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" name="math" value="0" /><br />
    <label>Physics:</label><input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" name="physics" value="0" /><br />
    <label>Computer:</label><input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" name="computer" value="0" /><br />
    <label>Science:</label><input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" name="science" value="0" /><br />

    <br />
    <button onclick="calculateGrades(this)">Calculate Grade</button>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```css
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
}
```

**JS**

```js
const totalElement = document.getElementById("total");
const averageElement = document.getElementById("average");
const gradeElement = document.getElementById("grade");

// Calculate the grades function
function calculateGrades(btn) {

    // find inputs
    const form = btn.closest("form");
    const inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");

    // define variables
    let total = 0;
    let used = 0;
    let average = 0;

    // loop over inputs
    for (const input of inputs) {
        // if value = 0, then do not use in calculation
        if (input.value == 0) continue;

        // convert input to number and add it to total
        total += Number( input.value );

        // increment number of subjects used
        used++;
    }

    // calculate average grade
    average = total / used;

    // display the values
    totalElement.innerText = total;
    averageElement.innerText = average;

    // get letter grade
    letterGrade( average );
}

// Calculate the grade letter function
function letterGrade(value) {

    // define variables
    let letterGrade = null;

    // if there is no value return
    if ( !value ) return letterGrade;

    // determine letter from value
    switch (true) {
        case value >= 90:
            letterGrade = "A";
            break;
        case value >= 80:
            letterGrade = "B";
            break;
        case value >= 70:
            letterGrade = "C";
            break;
        case value >= 60:
            letterGrade = "D";
            break;
        default:
            letterGrade = "F";
            break;
    }

    // display the grade letter
    gradeElement.innerText = letterGrade;
}
```